# Rvalue reference parameters take precedence over Lvalue reference parameters when an argument matches both overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Please considering the following example first (it's all about move semantics):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint> 
#include <cstring> 
class String{
    public:
        String() = default;

        String( const char * string){                         
            printf("Created!\n");
            m_size=strlen(string); 
            m_data=new char[m_size]; 
            memcpy ( m_data, string , m_size) ; 
        }
        //this COPY constructor should be invoked if the 1st constructor of Entity (bellow) is invoked
        String(const String& otherObject ){
            printf("Copied!\n");
            m_size=otherObject.m_size;      
            m_data=new char[m_size];   
            memcpy ( m_data, otherObject.m_data , m_size);  
        }
        //this MOVE constructor should be invoked if the 2nd constructor of Entity (bellow) is invoked
        String(String&& AutoTempObject){ 
            printf("Moved!\n");
            m_size=AutoTempObject.m_size;  
            m_data=AutoTempObject.m_data; 
            AutoTempObject.m_size=0;       
            AutoTempObject.m_data=nullptr; 
        }

        ~String(){std::cout<<"Destroyed!\n"; delete[] m_data; }
        
        void Print1(){
            for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < m_size ; i++){ std::cout << m_data[i]; }
            std::cout<< '\n';
        }
    private: 
        char * m_data;
        uint32_t m_size;  
};

class Entity{
    public:
        //1st constructor of Entity
        Entity(const String& StringObject) : m_name(StringObject) {}
        //2nd constructor of Entity
        Entity(String&& StringObject) : m_name( std::move(StringObject) ) {}

        void print(){ m_name.Print1(); }

    private:
        String m_name; 
};

int main(){
    //This declaration will invoke either "one of Entity's constructors" first; 
    // and from there invoke "one of String's constructors" accordingly
    Entity e1(String("StackOverFlow"));
}
```

Observation and question:

- When we remove "2nd constructor of Entity", this invokes 1st constructor of class Entity (1)
- But when we have both constructors for Entity, this invokes 2nd constructor of Entity instead (2)
- According to (1) and (2), the argument: String("StackOverFlow") must match both parameters of both constructors of Entity
- However when we pass the argument to instantiate an object of Entity - it didn't give ERROR but invoke the 2nd constructor instead.   My question is why?

Comment: What error did you expect to get? Did you expect it to complain about ambiguity?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i expects an error, but it didn't give any error when there is an argument matching both overloaded functions :)

Comment: Ok, so that's a _"yes, I expected it to complain about ambiguity"_ then.

Comment: I guess this `Entity(const String& StringObject)` requires an implicit cast from rvalue reference to const lvalue reference, so that's why second constructor is selected.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes I expected it or anything like that :) yes yes yes

Comment: `Entity(String&& StringObject)` is a better match than `Entity(const String& StringObject)` since it doesn't require a conversion.

Comment: Binding rvalue-reference to rvalue wins against binding lvalue-reference to rvalue in overload resolution.

Comment: @songyuanyao , meaning the argument String("StackOverFlow") is an r-value? I thought it is equivelant to an object so it should be an l-value instead?

Comment: @Crackie Exactly.

Comment: I thought it is equivelant to an object [/like return some temporaty object] so it should be an l-value instead?

Comment: @Crackie It's an object, a temporary object, but an rvalue. For example, `String s("StackOverFlow");`, `s` is an lvalue, it's the name of variable. You can find more definitions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

Comment: anyone knows what is the syntax to test if an entity is an r-value or l-value ? :D